# How to avoid instanceof when hiding a field

Tags: oop, inheritance, design-patterns

I will start off by saying I've read through quite a few of the questions that ask about avoiding instanceof but I couldn't really see any that quite fit the bill for what we're seeing. Please let me know if you do see any that address this specific point though!

There's an issue we're facing now where we have a class that is responsible for holding information about actions to be taken at particular times. These times can be of a single action or recurring over some period. There's one field we have (duration of an action) that is only valid for recurring actions. We initially had an Enum for the time type and a separate field for the duration as a part of a single class.

```
class Action {
    long duration;
    Enum timeType;
}
```

Change to:

```
class Action {
    TimeTypeStrategy timeTypeStrategy;
}

class RecurringTimeTypeStrategy extends TimeTypeStrategy {
    long duration
}

class SingleTimeTypeStrategy extend TimeTypeStrategy {
}

abstract class TimeTypeStrategy {
}
```

So with this modified code, we can essentially say that we can only even have one type or the other and that duration can only be a property of the recurring time type. However, this also means that whenever we want to action (or other classes that use action) to handle it based on its recurring time type, it needs to call instanceof on the timeTypeStrategy field to actually retrieve the duration and do whatever scheduling it needs.

One thought was that moving the effort of deciding what it means to be a particular time type can be brought up into the strategy itself. It feels like it should just based off of the name too but that requires changing some of the scheduling code by a fair amount and ends up breaking some of the paradigm that's been developed in just developing these schedules. Maybe that is the solution we need but it feels like it shouldn't be the only one.

As far as design patterns, is there a better method that doesn't lead to an instanceof code smell that allows the caller to decide what to do based on these fields?

Comment: what does represent `duration`? why only recurring actions have a duration? an Action that executes a single time does not have duration, it just happens instantly?

Comment: You can think of it that way. At the end of the day, the reason behind that doesn't reaaaally matter though since I can change the interface to IceCream and classes to BoringIceCream and FancyIceCream where FancyIceCream has sprinkleColor as a field. That'll equate to the same thing but you can then ignore the reasoning behind the specific field if you really want ;)

Comment: Visitor Pattern is an option if you don't expect to add new subclasses of `TimeTypeStrategy`. It works well with small, stable class hierarchies.

Comment: If `TimeTypeStrategy` is truly a Strategy object though, it should be using its own field(s) internally and not exposing its implementation details (i.e. encapsulation). Rather than asking for its data, tell it to do whatever needs to be done with the data. It seems like `TimeTypeStrategy` is just a data structure for holding the state of an `Action`. In that case, I would expose its data (and not call it a Strategy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is Visitor design pattern. You could have the following class hierarchy:

```java
abstract class Action {
   Enum timeType;
   abstract void Accept(IVisitor visitor);
}
```

```java
class SingleAction extends Action {

   override void Accept(IVisitor visitor) {
      visitor.Visit(this);
  }
}
```

```java
class RepeatedAction extends Action {
   long duration;

   override void Accept(IVisitor visitor) {
      visitor.Visit(this);
  }
}
```

Then you could have a visitor interface:

```java
interface IVisitor {
  void Visit(SingleAction action);
  void Visit(RepeatedAction action);
}
```

and the visitor implementation:

```java
class ActionVisitor implements IVisitor {

  void Visit(SingleAction action) {
    // Execute the action
  }

  void Visit(RepeatedAction action) {
    // Here you can access action.duration and schedule the action
  }
}
```